# Get the neural network weights out of a Tensorflow `Graph`

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, reinforcement-learning, rllib

I'm using RLlib to train a reinforcement learning policy (PPO algorithm). I want to see the weights in the neural network underlying the policy.

After digging through RLlib's `PPO` object, I found the TensorFlow `Graph` object. I thought that I would find the weights of the neural network there. But I can't find them. I see that this graph has ~1,000 nodes but I can't for the life of me find where TensorFlow is hiding the actual weights for the neural network. I looked through the nodes. I was told to keep an eye out for `tf.Variable` objects, but I couldn't find any. The closest thing I could find are nodes of type `ReadVariableOp`, but I couldn't find a `tf.Variable` in them. I did find a `tf.Tensor` in there, but I'm not sure whether it holds actual numbers, and if so how to get them.

Where do I find the weights of my neural network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a single-agent setup, do this:

```
weights = algo.get_policy().get_state()["weights"]
```

In a multi-agent setup, you'll need to specify the policy name:

```
weights = algo.get_policy(policy_name).get_state()["weights"]
```

Comment: `algo.get_policy()` just returns `None`, even after training.

Comment: how are you initializing your algo, `config = PPOConfig()` and `config.build` ?

Comment: Roughly like so: `from ray.rllib.algorithms.ppo import PPO; algorithm = PPO(config=config)`

Comment: I think you have a config issue, I update the code to launch a small config this will show you the weights

Comment: Your example helped me realize the difference. It should be `algorithm.get_policy('my_policy_name')` because I have a multi-agent setup.

Comment: Yes indeed if you have a multi-agent you need to get the policy of the desired agent, good to know you can pass the policy name